# Why the .whereEqualTo isn't working?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Why this working

```
Query firstQuery1 = firebaseFirestore.collection("Test").whereEqualTo("test", "1");
```

And this isn't working

```
Query firstQuery1 = firebaseFirestore.collection("Test");
firstQuery1.whereEqualTo("test", "1");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`firestore.collection("Test")` returns an object of type `CollectionReference` while `ref.whereEqualTo(..)` returns a `Query`

So instead of

```
Query firstQuery1 = firestore.collection("Test");
firstQuery1.whereEqualTo("test", "1");
```

it needs to be

```
CollectionReference ref = firestore.collection("Test");
Query query = ref.whereEqualTo("test","1");
```